# Python regex to remove tuples from the text

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I'm working on the text processing and I need to remove all the tuples from the text, tuples can have arbitrary number of elements (`e.g. () or (1,2,3)`) ,but the elements will always be integers. Can somebody help me to write regex for this, I'm really new to regular expressions and I have no idea how to do it!
Kind Regards,
Dre

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Did you try solving it yourself first?

Comment: There are plenty of online resources to try regexes and fettle them until they do what you need. OS is not a *"write my code for me"* service.

Comment: `\((?:\d+,)*?\d*?\)`

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this:

```
a = 'This is (1,2,3) just () a test.'
re.sub('\([0-9,]*\)','',a)
#'This is  just  a test.'
```

*Note*: if this is the case you'll be left with some extra whitespace.

To deal with that you can use:

```
re.sub('\s+',' ',a)
#'This is just a test.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
text = '(4, 5, 2), (23, 13, 100), (43, 567, 1)'
data = re.findall("(?<=\().*?(?=\))", text)
final_data = [tuple(map(int, tuple(re.split(",\s*", i)))) for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[(4, 5, 2), (23, 13, 100), (43, 567, 1)]
```